# bar with asymmetric error bounds in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I want to draw a bar with error bounds like this http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9377-barerror. There are many scripts to do this around that combine bar() and errorbar(). But all I found can only deal with symmetric errors. Can anyone show me how to add asymmetric error bounds like errorbar(X,Y,L,U) but on bar, not on curve? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can plot errorbars over your bar chart:

```
 data = 1:10;
 eH = rand(10,1);
 eL = rand(10,1);

 figure;
 hold all;
 bar(1:10, data)
 errorbar(1:10, data, eL, eH, '.')
```

Comment: What if the data is a matrix?