# How to plot asymnmetric errors with errorbar

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I would like to create a plot like pages 15/16:

comisef.eu/files/wps031.pdf

The example below gets close but only allows for symmetric error bars:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35294-matlab-plot-gallery-errorbar-plot/content/html/Errorbar_Plot.html

This example has asymmetric errorbars but only when plotted against the bar graph values
[bar with asymmetric error bounds in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816663/bar-with-asymmetric-error-bounds-in-matlab)

Is it possible to have asymmetric errorbars like in the first example shown but without the need for the bar graph?

Thanks Baz

I also have a question where I try to achieve the same thing with boxplot but I'm not sure which (if indeed either of them can) can do it.

[Matlab Boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224615/matlab-boxplots)

```
x = 1985:.05:2001; % x data
grad_ = rand(1,length(x))*.3; % graduated stuff
grad_2 = rand(1,length(x))*.3;
grad_3= rand(1,length(x))*.3;
h = subplot(1,3,1);

errorbar(grad_,x,grad_2,grad_3,'o');
axis(h, [0 0.6 1985 2001])
set(h, 'Ytick', x(1):x(end), 'Xtick', 0:.15:.6, 'YDir','reverse', 'YGrid', 'on');
xlabel('Gradient Search')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matlab function [errorbar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html) can create an asymmetric error bar and does not require a bar graph.

```
close all
x = 1:3;
y = [4 6 3];
lower = [1 4.5 0];
upper = [4.2 2 4];

errorbar(x, y, lower, upper, 'o')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
x = 1985:.05:2001; % x data
grad_ = rand(1,length(x))*.3; % graduated stuff
h = subplot(1,3,1);
plot(grad_,x); % flip x and y for vertical plot
axis(h, [0 0.6 1985 2001])
set(h, 'Ytick', x(1):x(end), 'Xtick', 0:.15:.6, 'YDir','reverse', 'YGrid', 'on');
xlabel('Gradient Search')

diff_ = rand(1,length(x)).^2 *.15; % differential stuff
h = subplot(1,3,2);
plot(diff_,x);
set(h,'yticklabel',[], 'Ytick', x(1):x(end), 'Xtick', 0:.15:.6, 'YDir','reverse', 'YGrid', 'on');
axis(h, [0 0.6 1985 2001])
xlabel('Differential Evolution')

delta_ = rand(1,length(x)).^2 *.2 - .2; % delta stuff
h = subplot(1,3,3);
plot(delta_,x);
set(h,'yticklabel',[], 'Ytick', [], 'Xtick', -.15:.15:.15, 'YDir','reverse', 'XGrid', 'on');
axis(h, [-.15 .15 1985 2001])
xlabel('\Delta of medians')
```

Comment: First off thank you very much! In this case you should both get credit!! Is is possible to put the errorplot shown above into your framework? That would be the prefect solution.

Comment: OK had a go (so code in my edited question) very clse not but unfortunately the errorbars appear in the vertical orientation is it possible to rotate them?

Comment: yeah, I was looking into that, I don't think so. Not without using a custom function from [fileexchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/loadFile.do?objectId=3963&objectType=FILE)