# Rotating Matlab Stem Plots

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Thanks to the help I received on this thread:

[How to plot asymnmetric errors with errorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226879/how-to-plot-asymnmetric-errors-with-errorbar)

I am close to achieving what I want, all that remains in for the third chart to appear as a series of discrete points, plotted solely as lines, as in the third column in the charts shown on pages 15/16 shown here:

comisef.eu/files/wps031.pdf

Stem seems to do what I want but I don't know hot to rotate the axes?
Or maybe there is some other way to do it?

```
   x = 1985:.5:2001; % x data
   grad_ = rand(1,length(x))*.3; % graduated stuff
   grad_2 = rand(1,length(x))*.3;
   grad_3= rand(1,length(x))*.3;
   h = subplot(1,3,1);
   %plot(grad_,x); % flip x and y for vertical plot
   herrorbar(grad_,x,grad_2,grad_3,'.');
   axis(h, [0 0.6 1985 2001])
   set(h, 'Ytick', x(1):x(end), 'Xtick', 0:.15:.6, 'YDir','reverse', 'YGrid', 'on');
   xlabel('Gradient Search')

   diff_ = rand(1,length(x)).^2 *.15; % differential stuff
   h = subplot(1,3,2);
   plot(diff_,x);
   set(h,'yticklabel',[], 'Ytick', x(1):x(end), 'Xtick', 0:.15:.6, 'YDir','reverse', 'YGrid', 'on');
   axis(h, [0 0.6 1985 2001])
   xlabel('Differential Evolution')

   delta_ = rand(1,length(x)).^2 *.2 - .2; % delta stuff
   h = subplot(1,3,3);
   %plot(delta_,x);
   stem(x,delta_);
   view(90,90);
   set(h,'yticklabel',[], 'Ytick', [], 'Xtick', -.15:.15:.15, 'YDir','reverse', 'XGrid', 'on');
   axis(h, [-.15 .15 1985 2001])
   xlabel('\Delta of medians')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with [`view`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/view.html):

```
stem(1:20,randn(1,20))
view(90,90)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi that certainly helps, but in the code above when I execute the stem command the stems are shown eminating from the horizontal axis, after view([90,90]), they emerge from the left vertical axis not from the center line as shown above? And it gets worse! After the set command they originate from the right hand vertical axis, and after the axis command the emerge from the top horizontal axis! I just want them to be like your example above but to retain the scaling and labeling commands?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Maybe your `set` or your `axis` lines have to be adjusted. Could you provide self-contained code? That is, with actual numbers in your `stem` line instead of variables, so that I can run it

Comment: OK please see edited question above, if you step through the third block of code you will see that after the view(90,90) command everything looks fine. But the last three commands seem to screw everything up! Those commands actually relate to the commented out plot commmand (shown just above stem), feel free to uncomment that command to see what the graph should look like. I guess I need to translate those last three lines from the plot commands to their stem equivalents. (I had hoped they would be the same but apparently not!)

Comment: It seems `axis` and `set` reset the view. So: after `stem`, put the `axis` line first, and with its arguments reversed: `axis(h,[1985 2001 -.15 .15])`. Then the `set` line, but I think you don't want the `'reverse'` option, so: `set(h,'yticklabel',[], 'Ytick', [], 'Xtick', -.15:.15:.15, 'XGrid', 'on');`And lastly `view(90,90)`.

Comment: Thank you it's 99% there but it doesn't show the scale on the horizontal axis? And the label of "delta of medians" should be shown below the x-axis not the y-asis.

Comment: Change `set` line (in the same place where it is now) to `set(h,'Xtick', -.15:.15:.15, 'XGrid', 'on');`. And replace the `xlabel` line by `ylabel('\Delta of medians')`

Comment: Perfect thank you. May I also ask if you know how I can add a label to the top of the graph, covering all three graphs?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry. The `title` command is for per axis. Maybe in Matlab Central File Exchange you will find something